# Keyboard shortcuts for spatial navigation between open windows (Switch to the window to the left/right/top/bottom of the current one)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz, application-switcher, ux

Is there a program or utility that would let me map keyboard shortcuts for switching between open windows according to their relative placement on the screen? For example: I have three windows, one on the left, one on the right and one below them. The top-left one is currently focused. I press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (for example) and the focus jumps to the window to the right. Then I press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> and the focus jumps to the bottom window. You get the idea.

So, is there an utility for that? Or perhaps some settings in Ubuntu or Compiz? I don't seem to find anything like it.

For me, this would be much more usable than switching with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Also, I don't want to use a tiling window manager. I'm quite happy with unity. Just having this spatial navigation on top of it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after some quite extensive googling, I couldn't find anything like this, so I threw together my own solution: [Spatial Window Switcher](https://github.com/madadam/Spatial-Window-Switcher). It is very simple and probably has bugs, but so far fulfills my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Neither I found something useful for Lubuntu. So I ended up with my own small [WindowsSwitcher](https://bitbucket.org/gekannt/windowsswitcher/overview)

Now to navigate to the necessary windows it's enough to click  Windows+1, Windows+2 and so on.